# Failed redirect for container for log

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2, cloudera-cdh

Recently we upgraded to YARN with CDH 5.

> (Version : 2.3.0 cdh5.1.3, r8e266e052e423af592871e2dfe09d54c03f6a0e8)

I was trying to access logs of failed job from Resource Manager by clicking logs on ApplicationMaster but I got following error:

> Failed redirect for container_1412602970010_0037_01_000002 Failed
>   while trying to construct the redirect url to the log server. Log
>   Server url may not be configured Container does not exist.

Also in `pig/mapreduce` job we are seeing following warnings:

> INFO: 2014-10-07 15:42:19,134 [main] WARN 
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation -
>   PriviledgedActionException as:jobs (auth:SIMPLE)
>   cause:java.io.IOException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException):
>   Could not load history file
>   hdfs://prod-hadoop:8020/user/history/done_intermediate/jobs/job_1412706451566_0032-1412710613932-jobs-PigLatin%3Aclk_imp_join_2014%2D10%2D04T13-1412710831122-14-2-SUCCEEDED-root.jobs-1412710694546.jhist

am I missing anything in configuration ?

Comment: I am having a very similar issue but for Spark apps. I have posted it here - https://stackoverflow.com/q/75732019/3061686