# "Failed redirect" for container logs of completed applications on Spark History server

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

## My issue

I am trying to view my Spark application's logs on Spark History server after they have completed but seeing a "Failed redirect" page on the History UI. My Spark applications run on Yarn.

I am expecting to see the executor (container) logs when I click on `stdout` or `stderr` on the "Executors" page of an application on the Spark History web UI.
Instead I am seeing a "Failed redirect" page (screenshot attached).

[image: UI unable to show logs after application completes.]

My Spark & Hadoop versions are `3.3.0` & `3.3.1` respectively.

## What I have tried so far

My configurations so far (only adding configs which seem related):

spark-defaults.conf

```
## Spark History Server
spark.yarn.historyServer.address                my-spark3-history-server.com
spark.eventLog.enabled                          true
spark.eventLog.compress                         false
spark.eventLog.dir                              s3a://TMP_BUCKET/PREFIX/spark3/application-history
spark.history.fs.logDirectory                   s3a://TMP_BUCKET/PREFIX/spark3/application-history
spark.history.fs.cleaner.enabled                true
spark.history.fs.cleaner.maxAge                 7d
spark.history.fs.inProgressOptimization.enabled true
spark.history.store.maxDiskUsage                200g
spark.history.store.path                        /<some-dir>/spark-history
## Uncommenting below line just makes the log URL redirect to Spark-History server's main page
# spark.history.custom.executor.log.url           https://my-spark3-history-server.com/jobhistory/logs/{{NM_HOST}}:{{NM_PORT}}/{{CONTAINER_ID}}/{{CONTAINER_ID}}/{{USER}}/{{FILE_NAME}}?start=-4096
```

yarn-site.xml

```xml
    <property>
        <name>yarn.log-aggregation-enable</name>
        <value>true</value>
        <description>
            Whether to enable log aggregation. Log aggregation collects each container's logs 
            and moves these logs onto a file-system, for e.g. HDFS, after the application 
            completes. Users can configure the "yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir" 
            and "yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir-suffix" properties to determine where 
            these logs are moved to. Users can access the logs via the Application Timeline Server.
        </description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.log.server.url</name>
        <value>https://my-spark3-history-server.com/jobhistory/logs/</value>
        <description>URL for log aggregation server</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.log-aggregation.roll-monitoring-interval-seconds</name>
        <value>1800</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir</name>
        <value>s3a://BUCKET_NAME/PREFIX_NAME/yarn3_logs/</value>
        <description>Where to aggregate logs to.</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.log-aggregation.retain-seconds</name>
        <value>604800</value>
        <description>
            How long to keep aggregation logs before deleting them.  -1 disables. 
            Be careful set this too small and you will spam the name node.
            We set to 7 days.
        </description>
    </property> 
    <property>
        <name>yarn.log-aggregation.retain-check-interval-seconds</name>
        <value>-1</value>
        <description>
            How long to wait between aggregated log retention checks.
            If set to 0 or a negative value then the value is computed as one-tenth
            of the aggregated log retention time. Be careful set this too small and
            you will spam the name node.
        </description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs</name>
        <value>{{ yarn_local_dirs }}</value>
    </property>
```

I can see data in S3 under directories for both - `spark.eventLog.dir` & `yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir`.

[This article](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html) claims that ***You need to have both the Spark history server and the MapReduce history server running*** - Is this true even if I have no MR jobs (i.e. my Yarn is running only Spark jobs)?